# what is the logic or Syntax behind unique() function in R?

Tags: r

I know that the unique() function returns the original vector after removing the duplicate values. But how it works? Can you provide me some logic, hint, or syntax behind it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The syntax is described in the documentation. The logic is described in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, you can see the source code of a function just by typing its name without parentheses.

```
> unique
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, ...) 
UseMethod("unique")
<bytecode: 0x000001f67dad5d48>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

However in this case, `unique` is a special (generic) function. From [Advanced R by Hadley](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html):

> A generic function defines an interface, which uses a different
> implementation depending on the class of an argument (almost always
> the first argument). Many base R functions are generic

So in order to check if the function is generic or not (you can basically guess because it is using `UseMethod` to do the dispatch, but anyway):

```
install.packages("sloop")
> sloop::ftype(unique)
[1] "S3"      "generic"
```

This means that the logic you're asking for depends on the underlying `class` (the type if you will) of the object you're passing to it. In order to see all the different implementations of `unique`,

```
> sloop::s3_methods_generic("unique")
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  generic class           visible source             
  <chr>   <chr>           <lgl>   <chr>              
1 unique  array           TRUE    base               
2 unique  bibentry        FALSE   registered S3method
3 unique  data.frame      TRUE    base               
4 unique  default         TRUE    base               
5 unique  Interval        FALSE   registered S3method
6 unique  matrix          TRUE    base               
7 unique  numeric_version TRUE    base               
8 unique  POSIXlt         TRUE    base               
9 unique  warnings        TRUE    base
```

If you use `unique` on a **matrix** for example the logic will be

```
> base:::unique.matrix
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, MARGIN = 1, fromLast = FALSE, 
    ...) 
{
    if (!isFALSE(incomparables)) 
        .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
    dx <- dim(x)
    ndim <- length(dx)
    if (length(MARGIN) != 1L || (MARGIN > ndim)) 
        stop(gettextf("MARGIN = %s is invalid for dim = %s", 
            paste(MARGIN, collapse = ","), paste(dx, collapse = ",")), 
            domain = NA)
    temp <- if ((ndim > 1L) && (prod(dx[-MARGIN]) > 1L)) 
        asplit(x, MARGIN)
    else x
    args <- rep(alist(a = ), ndim)
    names(args) <- NULL
    args[[MARGIN]] <- !duplicated.default(temp, fromLast = fromLast, 
        ...)
    do.call("[", c(list(x), args, list(drop = FALSE)))
}
<bytecode: 0x000001f605f062f8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

if used on a **data.frame**, it will be the below and so on.

```
> base:::unique.data.frame
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (!isFALSE(incomparables)) 
        .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
    x[!duplicated(x, fromLast = fromLast, ...), , drop = FALSE]
}
<bytecode: 0x000001f605f07b18>
<environment: namespace:base>
```